# How can I add segments to ActivatedRoute?

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-activatedroute

In angularJS, when using UI-Router, you were able to essentially name routes as each state had a name and you could navigate to that route.

For example:
`$stateProvider.state("base", { url: "/", controller: "baseController" });`
and then to navigate to that route you could do something like:
`$state.go("base");`

I am trying to do the same thing in angular v5.2 with **ActivatedRoute**.

The component I am in has a route of: `base/:acctId/:session/upsells/:id/:type`

and I want to navigate to `base/:acctId/:session/config/:id/:type`

I want to add a dynamic segment to the ActivatedRoute that will fill in `config/:id` so that when I navigate using the Router I can append the `:type`.

So from the component I am in (`base/:acctId/:session/upsells/:id/:type`), I want to navigate to another route after adding a couple segments to the ActivatedRoute and calling:
`this.router.navigate([type], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute }`

There isn't much in the documentation about modifying the ActivatedRoute and I have tried modifying the params but it seems that the Router doesn't use the params to navigate. I have tried doing something similar to [Viktor Savkin's comment on this github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13562#issuecomment-268528537) but again I am not sure of the Router.navigate functions behavior.

I've used `this.router.createUrlTree(['./config', configId, idd], { relativeTo: this.route.parent})` to yield a url tree that is exactly what I need but the problem is that the this.router.navigate function takes an ActivatedRoute object to navigate relative to instead of a UrlTree object. Is there a map to create an ActivatedRoute object from a url tree?

My router configuration looks like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "base/:acctId/:session",
        children: [
            {
                path: "config/:configid/:idd",
                component: ListViewItemDetailComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: "type1", <----- i want to get here
                        component: type1Component
                    },
                    {
                        path: "type2",
                        component: type2Component
                    },
                    {
                        path: "type3",
                        component: type3Component
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: "upsells/:id/:type", <------ I am here
                component: UpsellsComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense, and thank you for your time.

Comment: Well to understand how routing segments are configured, you will also have to add your routing configuration. The `relativeTo` option in `router.navigate` will depend on the routing configuration.

Comment: @planet_hunter oh shoot, sorry about that. I've added my routing configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [stackblitz POC](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkfnfe) where I have added same routing configuration.

Basically, I have used following routing logic to route to the specified `type1` route -

```
this._router.navigate(['./config/1/2/type1'], {
  relativeTo: this._ActivatedRoute.parent
});
```

`this._ActivatedRoute.parent` gets up to the parent route viz. `base/:acctId/:session` & then a relative path is given to reach `type1` viz. `./config/1/2/type1`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't really what I'm looking for. I will update my question to try and clarify. Thank you for taking the time to respond though.